# how to send variable to another activity from for (or while) loop

Tags: java, android, for-loop, android-activity, android-button

i'm new to android and i have a problem. i want to sent variable "adresa" from for (or while) loop to another activity when click on button, but allways send last value from loop.
here is code:
PS. sorry for my english
this is first activity

```
package com.example.locationtracker;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Button;

public class DatabasesActivity extends Activity {

public static String adresa;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final DBAdapter2 db = new DBAdapter2(this);     



    //---get a posao---
    db.open();
    final Cursor c = db.getPosao(0);

    if (c.moveToFirst()){

        final int x = 0;
        final LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//          while (c.moveToNext()) {
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {


            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            final Button button = new Button(this) ;

            button.setId(x+1);
            button.setText("id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
                    "Ime: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                    "Adresa: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
                    "Telefon: " + c.getString(3) + "\n" +
                    "Napomena: " + c.getString(4) + "\n" +
                    "Status:  " + c.getString(5));
            button.setLayoutParams(params);

            adresa = c.getString(2);

            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Perform action on click   
                    Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(DatabasesActivity.this, PrikazMape.class);
                    activityChangeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    activityChangeIntent.putExtra("add", adresa);

                   DatabasesActivity.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);
                }
            });
          //Add button to LinearLayout
            ll.addView(button);
           //Add button to LinearLayout defined in XML
            lm.addView(ll);
        } 
    }   



    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "No contact found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    db.close();     


    try {
        String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() +
            "/databases";
        File f = new File(destPath);
        if (!f.exists()) {              
            f.mkdirs();
            f.createNewFile();

            //---copy the db from the assets folder into 
            // the databases folder---
            CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("mydb"),
                new FileOutputStream(destPath + "/MyDB"));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, 
OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    //---copy 1K bytes at a time---
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
}


}
```

and second

```
package com.example.locationtracker;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class PrikazMape extends Activity {

double latitude;
double longtitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);



    Intent mInt = getIntent();
    String adresa = mInt.getStringExtra("add");


    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(PrikazMape.this);

    try {
        List<Address> addresses =
    geoCoder.getFromLocationName(adresa, 1); 
        if (addresses.size() >  0) {
            latitude = addresses.get(0).getLatitude(); 
            longtitude = addresses.get(0).getLongitude(); }

    } catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace(); }


  LatLng pos = new LatLng(latitude, longtitude);

    // Get a handle to the Map Fragment
    GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(pos, 13));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title(adresa)
            .snippet("Ovde nešto napiši.")
            .position(pos));


}


}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting up multiple buttons, but you only have one `adresa` for the whole object.  When you say

```
adresa = c.getString(2);
```

you will overwrite the value that was previously in `adresa`.  The problem, though, is that setting up the listener:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click   
            Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(DatabasesActivity.this, PrikazMape.class);
            activityChangeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            activityChangeIntent.putExtra("add", adresa);

            DatabasesActivity.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);
 }
```

does **not** copy the current value of `adresa` into the listener when you set it up.  It just says that when the button is clicked, to run the code in `onClick`; and that code will use whatever string `adresa` currently has, which will be whatever it was last set to in the loop.

One way to solve this is to define your own class that implements `OnClickListener`, instead of relying on an anonymous class.  Then you can add a constructor that lets you store the address in the listener.

```
private class OnClickListenerWithAdresa {
    private String mAdresa;
    public OnClickListenerWithAdresa(String adresa) {
        this.mAdresa = adresa;
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click   
        Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(DatabasesActivity.this, PrikazMape.class);
        activityChangeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        activityChangeIntent.putExtra("add", mAdresa); // NOTE use the listener's private field
        DatabasesActivity.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);
    }
}
```

and then, inside your loop, to set the listener:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListenerWithAdresa(adresa));
```

This *will* take the current value of `adresa` and copy the `String` reference to the new `OnClickListenerWithAdresa`.  This will ensure that the correct `adresa` is used for each button.

Another way, that I think is less clean, is to define a `final` variable inside the loop, before setting up the listener:

```
        final String adresaForListener = adresa;

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click   
                Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(DatabasesActivity.this, PrikazMape.class);
                activityChangeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                activityChangeIntent.putExtra("add", adresaForListener);

               DatabasesActivity.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);
            }
        });
```

This works because you're declaring the new `final` variable *inside* the loop, and then using it inside the anonymous class; the end result will be that a new `adresaForListener` variable will be created each time you create a new listener, so therefore each listener will have its own.  It's called a "closure".